# Print a pattern to display numbers up to 5 rows and 5 columns like 5 4 3 2 1 and in next line 4 3 2 1 5 till 5th row

Tags: php, for-loop

This is a square pattern with each row having 5 columns and there are 5 rows and the pattern looks as shown below:

```
      5 4 3 2 1
      4 3 2 1 5
      3 2 1 5 4
      2 1 5 4 3
      1 5 4 3 2
```

My code is as below to get the pattern but I am not able reset the value in each when the counter comes to 1 and display in that respective column value.

Can anybody guide me where I am lacking the logic?

```
<?php
  $n=5;
  $count=5;
  for($i=5;$i>=1;$i--){ 
     for($j=$count;$j>=1;$j--)
     {
        if($count>=1)
           echo $j."&nbsp;";        
     }
     $count--;
     echo "\n";
  }
?>
```

Comment: There are many solutions to that problem. But I think my (using modulo) is the most simple, and the fastest one. It is always very important to search for that kind of solutions ;). Best regards to all answerers, and have a nice day!

Answer (score 5):

I think that this is a learning excercise, so it must be done with for loops.

```
<?php
$n=5;
for($i=$n; $i>=1; $i--) { 
    for($j=$n; $j>=1; $j--) {
        echo ($i + $j - 1) % $n + 1; 
        echo ' '; // cosmetics :)       
    }
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

% is a modulo operator. 6 % 5 = the rest from dividing 6 by 5 = 1.

Examples: 1%5 = 1; 5%5 = 0; 12%5 = 2.

---

This is easy excersice from modular arithmetic (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). Every new row is nothing else, than a simple addition operation but in the 5-mod number set (for each row starting from smaller number). And I think this is the best and one-line solution for this problem. In addition the operation is easy, and is not time consuming.

Best regards!

Comment: You forgot to echo the spaces. But otherwise, great answer

Comment: Thx. This is the best answer I can thought of. However in Your answer, there is a nice description of the problem. +1 from me, even with the pseudocode in other language ;). BR!

Comment: I could add the "actual" php code, but then I'd be doing ALL their work ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
$str = "5 4 3 2 1";
$arr_str = explode(' ', $str);
$imax_loop = count( $arr_str);
for($i = 0; $i < $imax_loop; $i++)
{
    echo implode(" ",$arr_str) . "\n";

    // Get the first element and pop it off
    $head_elm = array_shift($arr_str);
    // append the first element at the end of the array
    array_push( $arr_str, $head_elm);
}
```

Output

```
5 4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1 5
3 2 1 5 4
2 1 5 4 3
1 5 4 3 2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you make an array with your first row then you can [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) the first element and [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score 2):

If we change your set from:

```
  5 4 3 2 1
  4 3 2 1 5
  3 2 1 5 4
  2 1 5 4 3
  1 5 4 3 2
```

to

```
  4 3 2 1 0
  3 2 1 0 4
  2 1 0 4 3
  1 0 4 3 2
  0 4 3 2 1
```

it looks a lot more like (some number MOD 5)... so your loop can simply print (N % 5)+1

so what is N?

instead of looking at i and j as decreasing. maybe we can look at them as increasing and being subtracted from some number.

Lets say i goes from 0-4 and j goes from 0-4. (remember to look at the second block since the +1 happens after the MODULUS operation we are going to do.

lets assume we want to add i and j together and take them away from some number, initially 4 might look good since 4-(0+0) gives us the right first cell, but once we get to the end of the second row we'll be doing 4-(1+4) and well negative numbers cause issues with modulus. (Mathematics and programming languages often differ on their interpretations.

9 mod 5 is also 4 and we're never going to be subtracting more than 8 (when i and j are both 4), so 9 seems a better bet.

```
PSEUDOCODE

for i from 0 to 4
  for j from 0 to 4
    print ( ( 9-(i+j) ) % 5 ) + 1
    if j<4 print " "
  loop
  print newline
loop
```

To make the loop flexible for sizes other than 5:

```
PSEUDOCODE

for i from 0 to SIZE-1
  for j from 0 to SIZE-1
    print ( ( ( (2*SIZE)-1) - (i+j) ) % SIZE ) + 1
    if j<SIZE-1 print " "
  loop
  print newline
loop
```

Comment: Added an explanation of one approach to getting to "use modulo"

Comment: Very nice answer. I cant believe what are people "writing" here. This iss an easy one line excercise, while in some answers there are multidimmensional fors, ifs and whiles... :).

Comment: Thanks - I like to put my reasoning in for questions like this. Teach a man to fish and -- something something... oh yeah he'll sit in a boat and drink beer all day. :-)

Comment: Yeah. But I'm still impresed. In that case for n < 10 it is easier and faster to just echo the numbers (echo "5 4 3 2 1\,4 3 2 1 5...") than to run some of the proposed code-pies :P. Best regards, and have a nice day!

Comment: Mine would also need some tweaking if the number of rows/cols is variable (which is assume it should be). Basically, the magic numbers in mine (4,4,9,and 5) need to be determined based on the square size... the 4s should be SIZE-1, the 5 should be SIZE and the 9 should be (SIZE*2)-1, I think. It's late here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the issue is very simple, and the OP had most of it correct.
The conditions in his inner loop just needed to be reworked and needed an if condition to add '5' to the output to prevent overflow if the numbers slipped into the negative range

```
<?php
  $n=5;
  $count=0;

  for($i=5; $i>=1; $i--){

     // You still want to loop through here 5 times, because you need to print out 5 numbers
     for($j=5; $j>=1; $j--)
     {
        // The fun part is augmenting your output so the numbers don't ever slip below 0 or negative.
        // This is already partially achieved in the fact that the range of your values is 5.
        // So if the value slips below the desired threshold, incrementing it by your range will bring it back into desired range
        $out = $j - $count;
        if ($out <= 0) {
          $out += 5;
        }
        echo $out."&nbsp;";
     }
     $count++;

     echo "\n";
  }
?>
```

Comment: This is nothing else as simulating modulo operation :). Working, but complicated...

Comment: It's easier for him to explain to his teacher, than to have to explain how he learnt modulus arithmetic overnight :)

Answer (score 1):

$str = '54321';

echo $str."\n";

for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++){

```
$a=$str[0];


$var = substr($str,1);


echo $str=$var.$a;


echo "\n";
```

}

and if u not want to use substr function then try this

```
  $str = '54321';
  $len = strlen($str);

  $s= '';
  for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){  
          print_r($str);
          print_r($s);
          $s = $s.$str[$i];
          $str[$i] = '';  
          echo '<br>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code little bit:

```
<?php
  $limit=5;
  $count=5;
  for($i=5;$i>=1;$i--){ 
     for($j=$limit;$j>=1;$j--)
     {
         $count = ($count>=1)?$count:5;  
         echo $count--."&nbsp;";        
     }
      if($count<1)
        $count=$i-1;
      else
          $count--;
     echo "<br>";
  }
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qq7y-86ea)

Output:

```
5 4 3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 5 
3 2 1 5 4 
2 1 5 4 3 
1 5 4 3 2
```

Comment: I didnt downvoted it, but I've got an idea why someone done that. Using multi line ifs and whiles is like shooting to the bird with an artillery here. This is a simple one line solution excercise. Not every working solution is good. And this isn't in that case. If this is a NASA excersise for a space ship you just lost 10.000$ for additional few bits of memory on the ship ;).

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain where you can improve upon your logic for the said code. You want 5 rows and 5 columns of values i.e 25 values in that pattern. Your outermost `for` loop runs 5 times and accounts for the 5 rows which works.

However the inner `for` loop i.e:

```
$count = 5; //initially and gets reduced by 1 on every iteration
for($j=$count;$j>=1;$j--)
 {
    if($count>=1)
       echo $j."&nbsp;";

 }
```

The above code should produce the following output since you're terminating the loop as `$j` hits 1:

```
   5 4 3 2 1
   4 3 2 1
   3 2 1 
   2 1 
   1
```

I ope you understand why you get this output. It's because you're not taking care of the second half of the output. So , if you were to extend your logic, think of the output as two parts (for every row):

1. A list of numbers starting from 5 i.e. the `$counter` variable that you had set that changes but terminates at 1.
2. Another list of numbers that always start from 5 that would account for the second half and thus produce the expected output:

   ```
     //1st half    //2nd half
     5 4 3 2 1
     4 3 2 1       5
     3 2 1         5 4
     2 1           5 4 3
     1             5 4 3 2
   ```

So just adding another `for`/`while` loop after your existing for loop should take care of it. You might want to try something like this:

```
 $n=5;


 for($i=5;$i>=1;$i--){
   $count=5 - $i;
   $k = 5;

   //Takes care of the firs half
    for($j=$i;$j>=1;$j--) //because $i gets decreased every time any way
    {
       if($i>=1)
       echo $j."&nbsp;";

    }

   //Takes care of the second half
     while($count > 0){
       echo $k."&nbsp;";
       $k--;
     }
  echo "\n";
  }
```

Comment: I would appreciate if someone explains why the answer was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Step One: Lament the fact PHP doesn't have a builtin array_rotate that could actually run at C language speeds.

Step Two: Use a version of array_rotate from the comments on the PHP site that will serve in a pinch. (This version is probably horrible due to array_shift if used on large arrays, but meh in our case)

```
function array_rotate(&$arr) {
  $elm = array_shift($arr);
  array_push($arr, $elm);
  return $elm; // return the moved element value
}
```

Step Three:

```
$a = [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ];
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
  echo join(' ',$a) . PHP_EOL;
  array_rotate($a);
}
```

Step Four: ???

Step Five: Profit!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$n=5;
$arr = array();
for($j=$n;$j >0;$j--)
{
for($k = $n;$k>0;$k--)
{
    echo $k. " ";
}
echo implode(" ",$arr);
array_push($arr,$n);
echo '<br/>';
$n--;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$n=5;
for($i=$n;$i>=1;$i--)
{
  for($j=$i;$j>=1;$j--)
  {
    echo "$j";
  }
  if($i<$n)
  {
    for($k=$n;$k>$i;$k--)
    {
      echo "$k";
    }
  }
  echo"<br>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for ($i=0;$i<=33;$i++){
    echo"<br>".$i;
    for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
        echo $j;
    }    
    }
```